# Set variable in parent window from iframe

Tags: javascript, events, iframe

I have a parent document with an embedded iframe.  Inside the iframe I have an upload field.  Once the user selects a file to upload, I trigger a jQuery change event.  On that event I want to set a variable in the parent window to true, so that the parent knows that the upload has started.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Was trying this, but didn't work:

```
var test;
$("#newsletter_email").change(function() {
  parent.window.test = true;

});

$('#send').click(function() {
    if (test) {
        alert('File has been uploaded!');
    } else {
        alert('You need to upload a file');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Variables in the global scope are auto-exposed as DOM properties of their containing `window` object.

This means that

```
var foo = 'bar';
```

is analogous to

```
window.foo = 'bar';
```

Which means that you can read the global scope of *any* `window` object you can obtain a reference to.  What we can also imply here is that usage of `window` is *implicit*.  Even when you don't explicitly type "window.", it's there anyway.

And since frames themselves are *also* auto-exposed as DOM properties of the current `window` object, this means you can access any other frames' `window` object as well.

The `parent` property of `window` objects holds a reference the `window` object of that window's parent (if there is one). Since iframes most certainly have a parent window, then all this stuff I just typed boils down to this

```
// set the global variable 'foo' in the parent global scope
parent.foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking this can't be in a .js file, or the parent scope would be all screwed up?

Comment: No.  External files adopt the scope of the document into which they are included.

Comment: How does the document.ready function effect the scope of variables? I've noticed in a number of cases that often while inside document.ready variables become unavailable to functions outside. Thanks

Comment: @ErmSo - No more or less than any other function.  There's only two scopes in javascript: Global and Function.  So, variables scoped to a function are definitely not available in the global scope.

Comment: @makerofthings7 - no, not all functions are global. Function names are part of the symbol table just like variable names, and become scoped themselves. Writing `function foo(){}` is fundamentally no different than writing `var foo = function(){}`

Comment: I just tried this in nested iframes and discovered it works to: [code]window.top.jsVar = true //use window.top to get to the top parent form

Comment: @PeterBailey FYI you have an outdated comment here now that block scoping has come to js: [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) & [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Answer (score 5):

You can also store it in the localStorage and read and write from it, provided that both the main document and the iframe share the same domain.

Comment: Yeah, but not all browsers support this.

Comment: I realize this is a bit of necroposting but it's relevant to my work now and there are a couple libraries out there (store.js and store2.js) that extend the concept of localStorage to be browser-agnostic.