# Attache script to the visualforce parent page

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

I have added my visualforce page to Account page and found that I can set only fixed height. I wrote javascript solution for auto height. First part I added to the parentAccount page by adding new button with {!REQUIRESCRIPT("my_scipt_here")}, second part I added to visualforce page.

s it possible to add javascipt to the "parent" Account page without adding Custom Button?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to run javascript on a page other than by using a button (or maybe a link as a field), though it'd be good to know if there is one but I highly doubt it would be available, or if it is, supported.

Would overriding the Account view page with a full visualforce page be an option where you use an `<apex:detail>` tag to get the standard fields etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Visualforce components on page layouts occur as iframes.  If the domains match up, which may or may not be the case - you could inject JavaScript from the iframe to the parent.

This may give more details:
[Inject javascript function into parent window from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539069/inject-javascript-function-into-parent-window-from-iframe)