# Create CSV from html using flash, javascript, classic asp

Tags: javascript, flash, csv, asp-classic, innerhtml

Let me start by stating that my end goal is to create an Export to Comma Separated File (.csv) or Export to Excel button on a page of our site.  Our site currently has a search mechanism that returns the data in XML. That XML is loaded into a Microsoft.XMLDOM object.

```
Dim objXMLDom
Set objXMLDOM = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
```

...

```
Function LoadXML(strXML)
    objXMLDOM.loadXML(strXML)
end function
```

This XML data is parsed into a variable called `myData` and is displayed in an HTML Grid using different columns & rows.  Like I said above, ideally I would like to add a button to the page that can export to csv or Excel.  I've searched around and found that this is not an easy task when the code is in Classic ASP...so I found a semi-work around.

The workaround is to use [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify).  It's a jquery/flash script that allows you to copy code into the HTML of a DOM element and then pull that data back out *all on the client side*.  It works for the most part...the only problem I'm having is adding in a new line character.  I think it gets removed going into HTML and back out again.

Here's the code for how I put data into the element

```
for (i = 0; i < <%=RowCount %>; i++) {
    parent.document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += '\n';
    for (j = 0; j < <%=columnCount%>; j++) {
        parent.document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += myData[i][j];
        parent.document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += ',';

    }
};
```

Here's what I use to pull it back out:

```
function load() {
    Downloadify.create('downloadify', {
        filename: function() {
            return document.getElementById('filename').value;
        },
        data: function() {
            return document.getElementById('data').value;
        },
        onComplete: function() { alert('Your File Has Been Saved!'); },
        onCancel: function() { alert('You have cancelled the saving of this file.'); },
        onError: function() { alert('You must put something in the File Contents or there will be nothing to save!'); },
        swf: 'media/downloadify.swf',
        downloadImage: 'images/download.png',
        width: 100,
        height: 30,
        transparent: true,
        append: false
    }

    );

}
```

I really don't know very much Flash, but I've tried putting in different strings (`'<br>'`, `'&#13;'`, even `";:;"` ) and replacing them in the `data : function` part using Flash's replace method, but it seems to hang and never finish processing (i think this is because I needed to put the replace method in a while loop since the replace method only replaces one instance and I have many).

Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: that's the way the `Downloadify` plugin is already structured to work.  I think i'm going to scrap it and try to work it out using only ASP & Javascript...

Comment: @wvxvw - I can't believe I didn't see that! :-)  You're suggestion worked.  If you want to write it up as an answer, i'll accept it as the solution.  I did have to use this question as a reference too (because my data is in an iframe)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301540/set-variable-in-parent-window-from-iframe

Comment: We export to csv, excel, txt, and access.  All in less than 2000 lines of code :P  Yeah it is kind of a pain.  Though the 2000 includes things like translating the recordsets, decrypting columns, etc.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you have the ASP create a .csv file along with the html page?  It seems like that would be a lot easier.

Comment: This "answer" is more of a comment and ought to be added as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this awhile back when I was using Flash and ASP together.
I remember calling ASP from Flash and it hanging. I THINK the fix was to add a "response.end" to the end of the ASP page. That seemed to tell the server, "Done. Back to Flash now." Sorry I can't be more sure. It was a long time ago and I can't find the code.