# Unable to access global variable (syntax error?)

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

The story: I have three files, `Base.html`, `miniChallenge.html` and `miniChlgame.html`... I declared a global variable (hopefully I did so correctly) in `Base.html` with the following code:

#### Base.html

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clgteam;
    </script>
</head>
```

To clarify something, if I am using an iframe to display another html[miniChallenge.html], am I right to say that `Base.html` is the parent of `miniChallenge.html`?

In `miniChallenge.html`, I have radio buttons that have different values and the user selects one of them before clicking a button that prompts a popup confirm box. At this point, I want to write the value of the radio button (in my case, James88, but I do not want this to be fixed as there are several options) into the global variable 'clgteam', declared in [Base.html]. I do this with the following code:

```
window.opener.document.clgteam.value = chkedRadio;
```

where chkedRadio is the value of the selected radio button

After that, when the user clicks the OK button on the confirm box, the iframe will then load `miniChlgame.html` where there are two labels and one of them should display the value (James88) of 'clgteam', and I do so by using this code:

```
document.getElementById('awayteam').innerHTML =  window.opener.document.clgteam.value;
```

where 'awayteam' is the ID of the label.

However, it does not work and I've tried various methods. Please enlighten me!!

(I am complete new to HTML, CSS and JavaScript so please pardon my idiocy. I have searched online, seen various solutions, but I am still unable to adopt them to solve my problem.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301540/set-variable-in-parent-window-from-iframe

Answer (score 0):

```
window.opener.document.clgteam.value = chkedRadio;
```

can't work since `clgteam` is not an HTML element.

Depending on browsers capabilities (HTML 5 or not) you can achieve this using iframe communication.

Comment: how do i point to the global variable 'clgteam'? any suggestions?