# Kendo Modal Window ViewModel

Tags: kendo-ui

I have created a page Main.html in witch there is a ViewModel.
In this page there is a button that open a Window Modal and load in it a html page in ajax.

I want to use the viewmodel of the main.html in my window modal, but if I call the viewmodel it do error..

Does someone know how can I resolve?

Comment: Could you put some code? What error do you receive?

Comment: AFAIK if you load a page via `ajax` it uses an `iframe` for containing it. For accessing container page data from an `iframe` take a look into http://stackoverflow.com/a/1301645/1802671

Answer (score 0):

Load a partial view in to your modal and make sure it has the proper using statement to allow it to use your model:

```
@using YourApp.YourModels.TheModel
```

Comment: I have resolve.
in the main js i have put a return { viewmodel: viewmodel } so it function on the other js file.

thank you very much