# iframe contents not appearing on screen even when checking for onload event javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, settimeout, onload

We are trying to build an HTML game in which `abobe edge` is being used for animations and those animations are being inserted into `iframes`. We are trying to preload the `iframes` before removing the 'loading screen' so that the users won't see blank iframes initially.

Here is the code for loading the `iframes`.

We have a global variable `var middleBotLoaded = false;`

The following function tries to dynamically populate the `iframe` and once the `iframe` has loaded , we are assigning the `variable` to `true`

```
function _trackIFrameLoading()
{
    if (document.getElementById("botzmiddleidlesequence_iframe").attachEvent)
    {
        document.getElementById("botzmiddleidlesequence_iframe").attachEvent("onload", function() { middleBotLoaded = true; });
    } 
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("botzmiddleidlesequence_iframe").onload = function() { middleBotLoaded = true; };
    }


    document.getElementById("botzmiddleidlesequence_iframe").src = APP_BASE_URL + "blitzbotzidlesequence/blitzbotz/"+middleBotzId;
}
```

We have a method to check if the global variable has become `true` and if so , we are removing the loading screen.The method is being called in a `interval` of 500 milliseconds

```
setTimeout(_haveAllCharactersLoaded,500);

function _haveAllCharactersLoaded()
{
    if(middleBotLoaded == true)
    {
        $(jOverlay).fadeOut(800, function() {
            $(jOverlay).remove();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(_haveAllCharactersLoaded,500);
    }
}
```

The problem is that even after the loading screen disappears , the `iframe` contents take time to come up on the screen .

We have observed that the duration depends on the speed of the net connection , but then , isn't using `onload` the whole point of making sure that the contents have loaded.

Is there any other approach for dealing with this problem.

Thanks.

**EDIT** : I have to wait for two days before I can start a bounty but I am willing to award it to anyone who can provide a canonical answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have two answers here.

First, I think you should reconsider the way you're coding this game, unless it's a static, turn based game that only relies upon animations (think Pokemon.)

Second, I have a suggestion for you to try in fixing your code.

**First Answer:**

---

You asked if there is any other approach to dealing with this problem.

My first reaction to that, would be to skip using iFrames entirely. Adobe Edge may provide you with a good way to craft animations, but for use in a game engine you will only find yourself fighting against the design of how Adobe Edge handles it's animations.

Instead, I would recommend learning how to use HTML5's canvas element. Canvas is built to handle dynamically loaded content (such as your game engine will be generating.) I can only imagine the event of having particle effect animation overlayed onto a game character as he is hit by a weapon. With your current approach, would you place that in an iFrame? Then, how would you ensure that this particle effect is placed on the correct location on the object?

There are many resources out there to help you begin learning the code you need to make a true game engine in the browser. I would recommend beginning by learning how Canvas works. If you want to animate using the DOM, learn about requestAnimationFrame.

http://creativejs.com/

http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial

**Second Answer:**

---

I would recommend looking into the variable scope of your middleBotLoaded. This answer ([Set variable in parent window from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301540/set-variable-in-parent-window-from-iframe)) would be a good place to look.

Instead of using `document.getElementById("botzmiddleidlesequence_iframe").attachEvent("onload", function() { middleBotLoaded = true; });`
try using `document.getElementById("botzmiddleidlesequence_iframe").attachEvent("onload", function() { parent.middleBotLoaded = true; });`

Alternatively, try something along these lines:

onLoad event:

```
document.getElementById("botzmiddleidlesequence_iframe").attachEvent("onload", function() { parent.middleBotLoaded();});
```

Function to handle loading:

```
function middleBotLoaded()
{
        $(jOverlay).fadeOut(800, function() {
            $(jOverlay).remove();
        });
}
```

It's a better practice to directly call an event, rather than polling for variable changes using setTimeout.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Let us see if there are any more answers and then award you the bounty. Thanks again.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I guess nobody is going to answer anymore,will award the bounty. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: harsha, I would recommend taking some tutorials on Javascript as a language, and really plan out your game from a code side before you go any further into development. With games, you are always limited by your coding ability. Having a strong codebase allows you to build a good, rich game, I'd work on that first, and then do your animations and graphics.